# Split, for-loop with replace to lambda expression

Tags: c#, string, for-loop, lambda, split

I have a string `q.ACBValue` which has instances like **"v1,v2,v4"** or **"v3,v5"**. I want to convert the following code to a neater lambda expression

```
 string[] list = q.ACBValue.Split(',');

 for (int i = 0; i < list.Count(); i++)
 {
     q.ACBOption = q.ACBOption.Replace("value='"+ list[i] + "' ", "value='" + list[i] + "' checked=\"checked\""); 
 }
```

Comment: use string format : string results = string.Format("The value = {0}", list[i]);

Comment: what is the difference b/w my code and using String Format...same thing!

Comment: What is the ABCOption string? XML? Then I would prefer to use XML modification, e.g. with the string parsed into an XDocument.

Comment: My code is a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
q.ACBValue.Split(',')
    .Select(s => new
    {
        Search = "value='" + s + "' ",
        Replace = "value='" + s + "' checked=\"checked\""
    })
    .ToList()
    ForEach(tuple => 
        qACBOption = q.ACBOption.Replace(tuple.Search, tuple.Replace));
```

This solution uses `ForEach` method of the `List<T>` class. To make it visible, you have to convert previous sequence to list by explicitly calling extension method `ToList`.

There is another approach, in which you are aggregating the results along the way using the `Aggregate` extension method:

```
q.ACBOption =
    q.ACBValue.Split(',')
        .Select(s => new
        {
            Search = "value='" + s + "' ",
            Replace = "value='" + s + "' checked=\"checked\""
        })
        .Aggregate(
            q.ACBOption, 
            (res, tuple) => res.Replace(tuple.Search, tuple.Replace));
```